# map a 3 nested array javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, dictionary

```js
const aboutMe = [{
   "name": "frank",
   "about": [{
       "mood": "happy",
       "dinner": [{
         "first": "desert",
         "last": "noodles"
       }]
     },
     {
       "mood": "happy",
       "dinner": [{
         "first": "desert",
         "last": "noodles"
       }]
     },
     {
       "mood": "happy",
       "dinner": []
     }
   ]
}]

const AllBreak = aboutMe.about.map((dinner) => ((dinner.first, dinner.last)));


   const expectedOutput =["first": "desert", "last": "noodles", "first": "desert", "last": "noodles"]
console.log(aboutMe, AllBreak, expectedOutput)
```

so am trying to filter through a nested array learning from a tutorial I don't know why it returns cannot read property of map why is that pretty sure i filtered correctly according to the tutorial

Comment: `aboutMe` is an array, if you are interested only at the first element, you can so something like: `aboutMe[0].about` but i doubt about it

Comment: What is the expected output? Does `aboutMe` array always have a single object in it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Firstly, `aboutMe` is an array with an object that has an `about` property in it. So, if you want to access this property, you need to first access the first element of the array and then access the `about` property in it.
- Secondly, `(dinner.first, dinner.second)` doesn't actually make any sense here.
  Because when you have multiple expressions separated by commas in a bracket, each of those expressions get evaluated but only the last one is returned. So, here returning `(dinner.first, dinner.second)` is equivalent to returning `dinner.second`.
- So, if you only want `dinner.second` then just return that or put them in an array (or object) and return that.
- Also, since in your example it seems that it is not guaranteed that the `dinner` array would always have an object inside it, it is best to use [Optional Chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) here.

Please have look at the solution below:

```js
const 
  aboutMe = [{name:"frank",about:[{mood:"happy",dinner:[{first:"desert",last:"noodles"}]},{mood:"happy",dinner:[{first:"desert",last:"noodles"}]},{mood:"happy",dinner:[]}]}],
  res = aboutMe[0].about.map(({dinner}) => [dinner?.[0]?.first, dinner?.[0]?.last])
  
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 1):

`aboutMe` is an array, if you want to get the property of the first element, you can use indexing `[0]`

```js
const AllBreak = aboutMe[0].about.map(() => ...);
```

Comment: 1) `(dinner.first, dinner.last)` is same as `dinner.last`. 2) objects inside `about` array don't have a `first` property. They have a `dinner` property which in turn has objects with `first` as property

Comment: It is wrong indeed, I was only trying to point to the fact that `aboutMe` is an array and he should point to a specific item. I didn't look to the further functionality excuse me I will set this right.

Comment: I did not, I would never do that